# Cypress, not able to intercept a call

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-intercept

I am trying to intercept following call, that gets executed after click on SAVE operation.
Its a POST 201 call.
Sample request URL is : https://www.test.com/abc/def/ghi/jkl/1234/mno/pqr/stu/9876

where `1234` and `9876` are dynamic changing parts of url.

But, it is not getting intercepted, and I am getting below error:

```
Timed out retrying after 2000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 2000ms for the 1st request to the route: submissionCall. No request ever occurred
```

My test code is as follow:

```
cy.intercept(‘**def/ghi/jkl/‘+’*’+’/mno/pqr/stu/*’).as('@submissionCall’)
cy.get("button[class='btn save’]”).click();


cy.wait('@submissionCall').then((result) => {
    cy.log(response)
})
```

I have tried `cy.intercept(‘**/mno/pqr/stu*’).as('callToIntercept’)` but this also didnt work.
Can someone help me by pointing, what I am doing wrong and what are the other best possible ways of intercepting same?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In intercept method; you should change the url part like this:

```
cy.intercept("**/mno/pqr/stu/**").as('callToIntercept');
```

Also you should edit last part like this:

```
cy.wait("@callToIntercept").then(({ response }) => {
  cy.log(response.body);
});
```

I hope that works!